# Integer partitioning under constraints on number of parts and maximum elements

Tags: integer-partitions

I have an use case which requires storing and then looking up the integer partitions of numbers. So before I go and actually store all the integer partitions, I am actually trying to check if they are feasible.I have 3 questions associated with it.

**Question 1**

I am not actually storing all the partitions of the number rather I am storing only those which have 16 parts and maximum element used is 128 . Hence 2048 has 1 partition and everything greater than that has 0 partitions satisfying the constraints. So is there an upper bound or an approximation to find number of such partitions i.e `p(n,k,m)` which is number of partitions of `n` into `k` partitions with maximum partition element used being `m`?

**Question 2**

I found out that

`p(16,16,128) = 1` which is `1+1+...+1(16 times)`

`p(2048,16,128) = 1` which is `128+128+...+128(16 times)`

`p(17,16,128) = 1` which is `1+1+...+2`

`p(2047,16,128) = 1` which is `128+128+...+127`

And I checked for few more and they were similar. As in `p(n,k,m) = p(2048-(n-16),k,m)` and we could derive the other partition with the one I had. Is this actually true?

**Question 3**

What is the best algorithm that can be used to generate such integer partitions under constraints? I had seen some code on the internet which does fairly well but it doesn't eliminate the possibilities fast enough i.e for `p(2048.16,128)` it takes a lot of time even though there is only one such partition.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the following (infinite) (binary) tree:

[image: infinite tree of integer partitions]

It contains all partitions of any integer $n$ at its $n$-th level, and also as a sub-tree with same root. In the picture, for instance, the partitions of $7$ are in the dotted areas.

Notice that partitions of given length are arranged in specific sub-trees, as well as partition with given maximum part.

This make this tree very convenient for fast listing of (specific kinds of) integer partitions (Question 3); it is also helpful to derive expressions to count them (Question 1).

More details are available in: [The Lattice of integer partitions and its infinite extension](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008020). See in particular Algorithm 1 and Corollary 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot..This is actually pretty interesting.

Comment: Good! Please let me know if you do anything with it :)

Comment: Sure I am still checking the feasibility,let's see...But this really a great input

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually defining $p(n,k,m)$ to be the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts of size *at most* $m$.  One way to compute this is recursively by conditioning on the value $j$ of the largest part:
$$p(n,k,m)=
\begin{cases}
[n = 0] &\text{if $k=0$} \\
[1 \le n \le m] &\text{if $k=1$}\\
\sum_{j=1}^{\min(n,m)} p(n-j,k-1,j) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$